# Count data from database where current data is the max date

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have some data in my DB:

```
Item      date          qty
gum       2012-03-13    1
soap      2012-03-12    3
soap      2012-03-11    10
candy     2012-03-04    20
sugar     2012-03-01    2
```

I want If I select data for soap, i will get data like :

```
Item       date            qty
soap       2012-03-12      35 (counting all data until max(date) of soap)
           (even soap is have twice input but get the max(date))
```

I'm just have a piece of query:

```
SELECT Item,MAX(date) FROM list WHERE Item LIKE 'soap'
```

how to put `COUNT(qty)`, so i will get the result like above ?

Comment: You want to filter by `item='soap'` however you want to sum the `qty` without this filtering?

Comment: @BenRowe: i have edit my post, i want to count data until the max(date) of soap.

Comment: @nunu: So you want the max date for soap but the sum of all qty in the table in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your example is wrong. It should result in `33` not in `35` because sugar is from year `2013`. Gotcha :) Here is the query:

```
select item, max(date) MaxDate,
  (select sum(qty) from t t1
   where t1.date <= (select max(date) from t
                     where item = 'soap')
  ) as totalQty
from t t2
where item = 'soap'
group by item
```

Or maybe, if you don't like seeing twice 'soap', then this should work too:

```
select item, max(date) MaxDate,
  (select sum(qty) from t t1
   where t1.date <= (select max(date) from t
                     where item = @item)
  ) as totalQty
from t t2, (select @item := 'soap') init
where item = @item
group by item
```

Comment: good catch on data of 33 vs 35, but am sure it was just a type-o... and you probably expected that too, but correct anyhow.

Comment: it's count all data before the max(date) of soap, could I filter it just count in current month.actually I have so many rows data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Item, MAX(date), SUM(qty) 
FROM list 
WHERE Item = 'soap'
GROUP BY Item
```

Comment: it makes i get `qty=36`. i must stop counting in the max(date) of soap.It's mean i must get `qty=35`

Comment: [It should give you 13](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c69d/1). I got your question wrong, I thought you only wanted to sum qty for soap.